# Loop animation with javascript

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I got stuck on a looping animation till the end of page, so it should continue where it left off. Here is link to code pen

```js
var width = window.innerWidth ||
  document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
  document.body.clientWidth;
var granica = width * 10 / 100;
console.log(width);
var animacija = anime({
  targets: ".glavniDiv img",
  easing: 'linear',
  delay: 200,
  translateX: [{
      value: [0, 50],
      duration: 500,
    },
    {
      value: '+=50',
      duration: 500,
    }
  ],
  translateY: [{
      value: [-25, 25],
      duration: 500,
    },
    {
      value: '-=25',
      duration: 500
    }
  ],
});
```

```css
.glavniDiv img {
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 10%;
}

.glavniDiv {}
```

```html
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="glavniDiv">
    <img src="https://technabob.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/111711_rg_8BitHeroes_03.jpg">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
```

I tried with for loop and didn't work so i don't know if i tried it wrong way or what

Comment: I don’t see your for loop. Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: I tried whit loop didn't run at all then deleted it basically i put anime part into for loop but image stays in place

Comment: Also i tried to run second animation after this one but image resets on beginning position and then moves on so i don't know how should i save location after each aniamtion.

Comment: show us what you’ve tried otherwise we don’t know what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Never mind i got work around :D

Comment: If you figured out a solution to your own problem, then you have a responsibility to document it for anybody else encountering the same problem in the future. https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Ok sorry didn't know that i had to do that, will try to upload it tomorrow cus i deleted file it was just my testing :D